# AWS API Gateway doesn't receive post requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, slack-api

I connected slack-app to aws api gateway.Slack-app sends json file when event occurs.After every time event occurs slack sends post request to aws api gateway.I need to handle challenge parameter in post request and re-send it to slack.Problem is that I can't handle this post request in api gateway.I tried to handle post request in api gateway using

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')))
{
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "challenge":"$input.params().header.get('challenge')"
    }
}
```

No result

Comment: And what have you tried? You cannot ask without providing any errors or something you have tried.

Comment: @DerekMenénedez I changed my question.Can you re-read?